# Which Regression methods are suitable for binary valued features and continuous output?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, boosting

I want to build a machine learning model to regression on continuous output given binary valued features(0,1). the dimension of my problem is around 200. which of the flowing methods seems suitable for this kind of problem ?

SVR with different Kernels

Regression random forest

MARS

Gradient boosting with regression tree

Kernel regression (Nadya-Watson Kernel regression)

LSR and LARS

Stochastic gradient boostin'